# Search string to find substring multiple times in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string, so how could I check how many times a specific substring is found in the string?

For example,

```
String1 = "The fox and the hound"
```

, and I want to know how many times the word `"the"` appeared.

The idea I had was since "the" has length three, I could check every set of three characters in the string, but I am hoping there is a more efficient way.

Comment: refer to `indexOf(String)` and `indexOf(String, int)` in [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexToCountWords {
  public static final String SAMPLE_STRING = "The fox and the hound";
  public static final String SEARCH_STRING = "the";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // pattern to compare \\b matches word boundaries
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + SEARCH_STRING + "\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(SAMPLE_STRING.toLowerCase());
    //matcher.find() checks for all occurrances
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
      count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Sample String : " + SAMPLE_STRING);
    System.out.println("Number of matching strings : " + count);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StringUtils` to count like so:

```
String string = "The fox and the hound".toLowerCase(); // to lower

int count = StringUtils.countMatches(string, "the"); // count is 2
```